# Data type mismatch when querying a CSV with ACE OLEDB provider

Tags: powershell, oledbcommand

I am attempting to query a CSV file using the Microsoft ACE OLEDB provider.  When I add "**PrctBusy > 60**" to the where clause  I receive the Error "**Data type mismatch in criteria expression.**"  I have searched StackOverFlow and used google to search for solutions, I see this is not an uncommon issue.  From my readings it looks to be datatype issue.  The data in the column PrctBusy is all numeric.  I think I need to force it to be number but I have not found a solution.

Below is the code I am currently working with:

```
$ArrayNameUtil = "000198701258"
$CatNameUtil = "FE_DIR"

$sdLocalPath = "D:\Logs\SANData\Perf"
$InputCSV = "VMaxSANReportUtilFile.csv"
$csv = Join-Path $sdLocalPath $InputCSV

$provider = (New-Object System.Data.OleDb.OleDbEnumerator).GetElements() |     Where-Object { $_.SOURCES_NAME -like "Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.*" }
if ($provider -is [system.array]) { $provider = $provider[0].SOURCES_NAME } else {  $provider = $provider.SOURCES_NAME }
$connstring = "Provider=$provider;Data Source=$(Split-Path $csv);Extended Properties='text;HDR=$firstRowColumnNames;';"
$firstRowColumnNames = "Yes"
$delimiter = ","
$tablename = (Split-Path $csv -leaf).Replace(".","#")

$conn = New-Object System.Data.OleDb.OleDbconnection
$conn.ConnectionString = $connstring

$provider = (New-Object System.Data.OleDb.OleDbEnumerator).GetElements() |     Where-Object { $_.SOURCES_NAME -like "Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.*" }
if ($provider -is [system.array]) { $provider = $provider[0].SOURCES_NAME } else {  $provider = $provider.SOURCES_NAME }
$connstring = "Provider=$provider;Data Source=$(Split-Path $csv);Extended Properties='text;HDR=$firstRowColumnNames;';"
$firstRowColumnNames = "Yes"
$delimiter = ","
$tablename = (Split-Path $csv -leaf).Replace(".","#")

$conn = New-Object System.Data.OleDb.OleDbconnection
$conn.ConnectionString = $connstring
$conn.Open()
#
$sql = "SELECT TimeStamp, count(PrctBusy) AS Above60  FROM [$tablename] WHERE array = '$ArrayNameUtil' and Category like '$CatNameUtil' and PrctBusy > 60 Group by TimeStamp "

$cmd = New-Object System.Data.OleDB.OleDBCommand
$cmd.Connection = $conn
$cmd.CommandText = $sql

$dtp = New-Object System.Data.DataTable
$dtp.Load($cmd.ExecuteReader())
```

Comment: I haven't tried, but CSVs are untyped so surely the data is all string, and you'd need to cast PrctBusy to a numeric type before comparing it. -> https://www.codeproject.com/Questions/714884/Casting-value-while-reading-from-Excel-file -> either seems to be "you can't do it" or "use Access syntax"

Answer (score 0):

Because of the pointer from TessellatingHeckler to Codeproject and some follow on queries, I was lead to http://aspdotnetcodes.com/Importing_CSV_Database_Schema.ini.aspx.  I found that a schema.ini file in the same directory as the CSV file could specify the data type.

The schema.ini  file ended up in the following format:

```
[VMaxSANReportUtilFile.csv] 
 ColNameHeader=True 
 Format=CSVDelimited 
 Col1=Array Text Width 20 
 Col2=TimeStamp Text Width 20 
 Col3=Category Text Width 20 
 Col4=Instance Text Width 20 
 Col5=PrctBusy Short 
 Col6=QueUtil Short
```

I went through several revisions to get the data type correct for an ACE OLE DB provider.  If the columns are named the names need to be in the schema.ini file.